# Eaton Cutler-Hammer Plug-On Neutral (differences)

Tags: electrical

### 1. Introduction

I have an Eaton CH Plug-On-Neutral Panel (CH42BPN200K).

I need a 20 AFCI/GFCI Breaker.

I found two or more part numbers that are for an Eaton CH 20 AFCI/GFCI breaker.

1. CHFAFGF120PN (Eaton Catalog - City Electric Supply)
2. CHFPAFGF120CS / CHFP120DF (Home Depot / Lowes)

There may be more part numbers that I just have not found yet.

(Note: I wish I could figure out how to make the following images smaller).

---

### 2. Questions

Are the following two parts the same or different even though they look almost identical?

Is one part better than the other?

---

### 3. CHFAFGF120PN - Eaton Catalog / City Electrical Supply

Eaton Brochure and catalogs show the part number as **CHFAFGF120PN** (Single-pole 10kAIC 20 Amps - AF/GF plug-on neutral). I went by the the local Electrical Supply House and purchase this:

[image: Part Number - CHFAFGF120PN]
[image: Part Number - CHFAFGF120PN]

---

### 4. CHFPAFGF120CS - Home Depot / Lowes - $56.95

The Home Depot (and Lowes) appears to carry a CH Plug-On-Neutral breaker, but the part number is **CHFPAFGF120CS** (All-In-One Breaker). The part number on the device (CHFP120DF) is different than the part number on the box (CHFPAFGF120CS).

[image: Part Number - CHFPAFGF120CS]
[image: Part Number - CHFPAFGF120CS]

---

### 5. Eaton Brochure

[image: Plug-on neutral loadcenter brochure]

---

### 6. Eaton Catalog

[image: Eaton - Loadcenters and Circuit Beakers]

---

### 7. Reference and Sources

Eaton - Plug-on neutral loadcenter
http://www.eaton.com/ecm/groups/public/@pub/@electrical/documents/content/br00301006e.pdf

Eaton - Loadcenters and Circuit Breakers
https://www.eaton.com/ecm/groups/public/@pub/@electrical/documents/content/vol01_tab01.pdf

Comment: One catalog is dated 2014 and the other one is dated 2019.

Comment: I wouldn't get too concerned about model of breaker inside the box not matching the number on the retail package, they have to do something to differentiate the packaging. Sometimes when ordering light bulbs we could get a different availability options by adding BP (blister pack) to the part number. Different package, same bulb. Other suffixes would indicate 10 packs in little unmarked boxes.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I tend to get a little too hung up. I am trying to attempt to get the most current and reliable product. Sometimes a newer model is better, sometime it is not. I assume that the Subject-Matter-Experts (SMEs) / Professionals in the trade / industry know early on or have a reliable vendor contact to find out more about a product.

Answer (score 1):

### Eaton - Catalog numbers still to come

I found this, not sure where though. The last page has "March 2019".

Example:

New plug-on neutral catalog number is:

- CHFP120DF

Similar previous design catalog numbers:

- CHFAFGF120PN
- CHFAFG120

Now if I could only find these two AFCI Plug-On Neutral breakers:

- CHFP115AF (AFCI 15 Amp)
- CHFP120AF (AFCI 20 Amp)

---

[image: Catalog numbers still to come]

Comment: Yeah, Eaton has been doing a lot of part number changing on the CH PoN gear (breakers and LCs) to make it fit the new system they're inaugurating with the introduction of the BR PoN product line